# What's the appropriate Java idiom/pattern for recursive call?

Tags: java, recursion

What's the appropriate Java idiom/pattern for recursive call where I need to maintain an object across invocations? I see two options, but I don't like either of them.
Something like this:

```
class A {
   private ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

   public ArrayList foo (SomeType x){

      if(something) list.add(z);
      foo(y);

      return list;
   }

}
```

Or this?

```
class A {

   public ArrayList foo (SomeType x, ArrayList list){
      if (something) list.add(z);  
      foo(y, list);

      return list;
   }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to loop AND recurse.

Comment: Recursion is usually an alternative to iteration. More importantly, where did you get `y` and `z`?

Comment: I think you're confused about how recursion works.

Comment: If you don't know exactly why you need recursion, you don't need it.  https://www.google.com/search?q=recursion+vs+iteration

Comment: Ignoring the odd example, the two ways you present are the two choices for having access to the `List` and either is fine.

Comment: Sorry, bad example. That while loop is orthogonal to the recursion,  and not essential to the question. The use of the loop here is akin to going through a queue in a BFS function. I boiled down the sample code from a larger piece and didn't think to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would provide a `public` method that takes only the `SomeType` parameter.  It creates a new `ArrayList` and passes it to a `private` method that takes an `ArrayList` and does the actual recursion.  Also, the `while` loop is most likely unnecessary.  Recursion can be a replacement for using a loop.  Something like this should do:

```
public ArrayList foo (SomeType x) {
    return foo(x, new ArrayList());
}

private ArrayList foo(SomeType x, ArrayList list) {
    // Perform your recursion here, which probably shouldn't be in a loop.
    if (someCondition) {
        list.add(z);
        foo(y, list);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Once you get it working, you may want to add a generic type parameter to the `ArrayList`

Comment: Thanks, this is along the lines of what I was looking for. You're right about the while loop - it's not essential to the example. So there's no way to simulate variables with local scope but static life span?

Answer (score 0):

There is no idiom for recursive functions which is unique to Java. In general, the way recursive methods look like:

```
public <T> recursive(T t){
    if(stopConditionMet){
        return t;
    } 
    // modify t and call recursively
    T nextT = modify(t);        
    return recursive(nextT);
}
```

What you demonstrated in your question is a hybrid of recursive and iterative methods. The difference is that an iterative method does not call itself, but rather do all the work in a loop (until the stop-condition is met), which is why, in most cases, the iterative version is preferred (cheaper and safer to execute).

Answer (score 0):

You can just addrange on return from recursion:

```
 class A {

 public ArrayList foo (SomeType x)
 {
     List list = new ArrayList();
     while(/*some conditition*/)
     {
        if (something) list.add(z);  
        list.addAll(foo(y));
     }
     return list;
  }
}
```

If i understand your logic correcly